# jQuery div drop down on a click event

Tags: jquery, html, easing

I was looking to achieve the same effect as on the website http://www.wpnukes.com/demo/html/welcare/

Please notice the contact link on the top right of the screen next to sign in link, when you click on Contact a div drop down with jerks, How can I achieve this effect or some one please tell me the name of this effect so i can google it and can find a code. please, Thanks.

Comment: It looks to be a custom version of the `bounce` effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use jQuery UI for this type of effects. All they have done is a div with absolute position to contact button and display:none; The query on contact button triggers the effect. **Remember you should add the jquery Core plus UI file to your html.**

[**SOLUTION 1 - BOUNCE EFFECT - LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx65Q/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button" ).click(function() {
         $( ".toggle" ).toggle( "bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow" );
    });
});
```

[**SOLUTION 2 - EASEOUTBOUNCE EFFECT - LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx65Q/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function () {
      $('.login').toggle('slide', {
         duration: 1000,
         easing: 'easeOutBounce',
         direction: 'up'
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=jquery_149 I found something here, How can I make visible only when clicking on the button.

Comment: click on my live demo. you can find the working example there.

Comment: Thank you...Solution 2 looks good. Only thing can we do? Can we make box to appear only when the button is clicked.

Comment: please check solution 2 again.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/), there is some animate bounce effects

Answer (score 0):

Thats a custom jquery animation:

```
$("#link").click(function(e) {          
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#divToAnimate').animate({height: 'show', opacity: '0', filter: 'alpha(opacity=0)'}, {duration: 0}).animate({opacity: '.5', filter: 'alpha(opacity=50)', top: 58}, {duration: 300, easing: 'easeInBack'}).animate({opacity: '1', filter: 'alpha(opacity=100)', top: 24}, {duration: 200, easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    });
```